# How can I use TExtendedHelper on literals?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, class-helpers

With `System.SysUtils.TShortIntHelper` (and others) I can write:

```
output := 5.ToString();
```

to format the number `5` as `string`. As well, there is `System.SysUtls.TExtendedHelper`, but I'm unable to compile:

```
output := (5.0).ToString();
```

> E2018: Record, object or class type required

Other versions which don't work:

- `5.0.ToString()`
- `(1.0+5.1).toString()`
- `(5+0.).toString()` (says E2029: ')' expected but ']' found)

Versions which *do actually work*:

- `(1+5.1).toString()`
- `(1.1+1+5.1).toString()`
- `5.9e0.toString()`

If the extended value is declared `const`, it doesn't work either:

```
function TestFormat(): String;
const
  q = 5.5;
begin
  Result := q.ToString();
end;
```

But with a definition of `q : extended = 5.5;` it works. So, I'm wondering why the compiler behaves this way.

Comment: Using the traditional `Win32` compiler.

Comment: (wild guess) I see the pattern: an `Integer` constant is present (and get converted to `Real`) in every expression which works. Not guessing what it might mean, tho.

Comment: I'd suggest trying an explicit type-cast. E.g. `Extended(5.5).Frac;` Unfortunately I don't have an appropriate version of Delphi to test myself.

Comment: @CraigYoung, that would end up with "Illegal typecast".

Comment: @LURD Thanks. I certainly wouldn't have expected that.

Comment: I'd go for `'5.0'` if I were you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That was my first thought as well. However, there might be a desire to respect format settings of the user. E.g. `'5,0'` might be the expected string for some users.

Comment: Good point @craig

Comment: Thank you for all you input, I created a bug report and after fiddling afound a little, I found another way to express an extended literal which can use the helper: `5.9e0.toString()` works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You found errors in the compiler. Please report it in Quality Portal.

A workaround is to use the helpers class functions:

```
myString := Extended.ToString(5.5);
```

> ```
> class function ToString(const Value: Extended): string; overload; inline; static;
> class function ToString(const Value: Extended; const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): string; overload; inline; static;
> class function ToString(const Value: Extended; const Format: TFloatFormat; const Precision, Digits: Integer): string; overload; inline; static;
> class function ToString(const Value: Extended; const Format: TFloatFormat; const Precision, Digits: Integer;
>                            const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): string; overload; inline; static;
> ```

Comment: Submitted a [bug report, issue RSP-17093](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17093).